# Python Module: Inconsistent Output

Tags: python, vector, python-3.x

I have a module that is supposed to find the average value given a list of vectors.
The problem is that the returned value is inconsistent. Sometimes it gives me the expected output and other times it does not.

```
def find_average_record(sen_set, voting_dict):
    """
Input: a set of last names, a voting dictionary
Output: a vector containing the average components of the voting records
        of the senators in the input set
    """

    count = len(sen_set)
    total_set = voting_dict[sen_set.pop()]

    for senator in sen_set:
        for vote in voting_dict[senator]:
            total_set[vote] += vote

    return [x/count for x in total_set]
```

Example:

```
voting_dict = {'Klein': [-1,0,1], 'Fox-Epstein': [-1,-1,-1], 'Ravella': [0,0,1]} 
find_average_record({'Fox-Epstein','Ravella'}, voting_dict) 
# should =>[-0.5, -0.5, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the vote count from each senator as an index into the total votes. Don't do that. Use `enumerate()` instead. You also need to make a **copy** of the `voting_dict` list you assign to `total_set` to avoid altering the mutable list in place:

```
def find_average_record(sen_set, voting_dict):
    count = len(sen_set)
    total_set = voting_dict[sen_set.pop()][:]

    for senator in sen_set:
        for i, vote in enumerate(voting_dict[senator]):
            total_set[i] += vote

    return [x/count for x in total_set]
```

You could also use `sum()` on each column (use `zip()` to transpose rows and columns); this avoids altering any of the vote lists in place altogether:

```
def find_average_record(sen_set, voting_dict):
    count = len(sen_set)
    return [sum(col) / count for col in zip(*(voting_dict[sen] for sen in sen_set))]
```

Either version now returns the average correctly:

```
>>> find_average_record({'Fox-Epstein', 'Ravella'}, voting_dict) 
[-0.5, -0.5, 0.0]
```

Moreover, the lists contained in `voting_dict` are not altered.

Comment: @glglgl: +++ OUT OF CAFFEINE ERROR +++ REDO FROM START +++

Comment: In the first part of your answer, I don't believe you can rely on the ordering of the `voting_dict` and `sen_set` corresponding. Haven't figured out if that applies to the second part or not, yet...

Comment: @martineau: This has nothing to do with ordering. The OP removes *one* name from `sen_set`, then loops over the rest of `sen_set` to get other names. There is no assumption made about any order matching here.

Comment: @martineau: It doesn't matter *what* order the senator votes are being processed, you can sum numbers in any order you like.

Comment: Agreed...but the OP expects the function to return a vector, and I think they expect the values in it to be in the same order as the input set -- hence the complaint about inconsistent results. One really has no idea what order the `for senator in sen_set:` is going to produce, so the order of the values returned can't be predicted from the input arguments.

Comment: @martineau: The dictionary *values* are the vectors. They are being summed. They retain their order just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be wrong, since you've already accepted Martijn's answer, but I think this is what you want. I changed the senator set argument into a list so that the average values in the vector returned are in the same order as that list (and there is the same number of them).

```
def find_average_record(sen_list, voting_dict):
    """
Input: a list of senator names, a voting dictionary
Output: a vector containing the average components of the voting records
        of the senators in the input list in the same order
    """
    def average(vector):
        return sum(vector) / len(vector)

    return [average(voting_dict[senator]) for senator in sen_list]

voting_dict = {      'Klein': [-1, 0, 1],
               'Fox-Epstein': [-1,-1,-1],
                   'Ravella': [ 0, 0, 1]}
print(find_average_record(['Fox-Epstein', 'Ravella'], voting_dict))
```

Output:

```
[-1.0, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Comment: the output should be `[-0.5, -0.5, 0.0]`.